# How to add multiple services in one component in Angular

Tags: angular, service, components

ERROR in src/app/header1/header1.component.ts:3:30 - error TS2306: File 'F:/Angular-projects/lawyer-listing/src/app/services/state.service.ts' is not a module.

```
3 import { StateService } from '../services/state.service';
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.module.ts:40:30 - error TS2306: File 'F:/Angular-projects/lawyer-listing/src/app/services/state.service.ts' is not a module.

40 import { StateService } from './services/state.service';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: did you export that service or did you used @Injectable({ providedIn:'root' }) above class?, did you made two different service with same name ? if so rename one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a service many times, also you have to make your service `injectable`, for multiple service you can define services as below or make `methods` under a service.

```
--cart
  -- cart.component.ts
  -- ***

-- yourServiceFolder
  -- state.service.ts
  -- another.service.ts
```

**state.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StateService {
     myServiceMethod(){
        //return
     }
}
```

**cart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StateService } from '../yourServiceFolder/state.service';
import { AnotherService } from '../yourServiceFolder/another.service';

***

constructor(
   private stateService: StateService,
   private anotherService: AnotherService
) { }
```